# How to remove arrays whose element is not present in a list

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an `array` of arrays as follows:

```
array = [ 
  [ 'a0', 'a1', 'a2' ], # Array A
  [ 'b0', 'b1', 'b2' ], # Array B
  [ 'c0', 'c1', 'c2' ], # Array C
  ...,                  # Array ... 
  [ 'z0', 'z1', 'z2' ]  # Array Z
]
```

and would like to remove from it the arrays whose first element is not present in `list`:

```
list = [ 'a0', 'c0' ]
```

namely `Array A` and `Array C` (whose first element is respectively `'a0'` and `'c0'`) to get the following:

```
array = [ 
  [ 'b0', 'b1', 'b2' ], # Array B
  ...,                  # Array ... 
  [ 'z0', 'z1', 'z2' ]  # Array Z
]
```

How can I do that?

---

I would like to do a similar thing to the arrays whose second element is not present in `another_list`.

```
another_list = [ 'a1', 'c1' ]

array = [ 
  [ 'a0', 'a1', 'a2' ], # Array A
  [ 'b0', 'b1', 'b2' ], # Array B
  [ 'c0', 'c1', 'c2' ], # Array C
  ...,                  # Array ... 
  [ 'z0', 'z1', 'z2' ]  # Array Z
]
```

In this case, I would like to remove `Array A` and `Array C` (whose second element is respectively `'a1'` and `'c1'`) from `array` to get the following:

```
array = [ 
  [ 'b0', 'b1', 'b2' ], # Array B
  ...,                  # Array ... 
  [ 'z0', 'z1', 'z2' ]  # Array Z
]
```

Comment: You wrote that you want to remove the arrays whose first/second element is **not** in another array, but you seem to be removing those whose element **is** in another array. Not clear what you are doing.

Comment: We need to see the code you've written to try to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list = [ 'a0', 'c0' ]

array = [ 
  [ 'a0', 'a1', 'a2' ], # Array A
  [ 'b0', 'b1', 'b2' ], # Array B
  [ 'c0', 'c1', 'c2' ], # Array C
  [ 'z0', 'z1', 'z2' ]  # Array Z
]

array2 = array.reject { |sub| list.include?(sub.first) }
```

`array2` could just be `array` if you truly want to lose those items.  For other variations just change what element (`sub[1]`, or whatever) you're looking at.